# Async lambda and cannot implicitly convert Task.Task.List<Object> to List<Object>

Tags: c#, asynchronous, lambda

I have the following classes

```
public PhoneModel
{
    int PhoneID;
    string PhoneType;
    string PhoneNumber;
}
public ContactModel 
{
    int ContactID;
    string FirstName;
    string LastName;
    List<PhoneModel> PhoneNumber;
}
```

I need to display a list of contacts with all phone numbers of each contacts.

```
var contactList = await ContactBLL.GetContactList();
IEnumerable<ContactViewModel> contacts = contactList.ToList().ConvertAll(
    async c => new ContactViewModel
    {
        phones = (await ContactBLL.GetContactPhones(c.ContactID)).ToList(),
        firstName = c.FirstName, 
        lastName = c.LastName
    });
```

I am currently getting the compilation error saying "cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task.List to IEnumerable...." However, without the `async` call to get the phone list, it will work (of course without the phones). I can change the `async` function `GetContactPhones()` to sync function and it will work as expected. My question is there a way to make the code above work with `async` call?

Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Currently you're projecting your sequence of items into a collection of tasks that, when completed, can provide your view models.  You need to (asynchronously) wait until those tasks all finish if you want to have a sequence of those views.  You can use `Task.WhenAll` to do this:

```
var contacts = await Task.WhenAll(contactList.Select(
    async c => new ContactViewModel
    {
        phones = (await ContactBLL.GetContactPhones(c.ContactID)).ToList(),
        firstName = c.FirstName, 
        lastName = c.LastName
    }));
```